# gcc-4.2 on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: 14.04, apt, gcc

I need gcc-4.2 on Ubuntu Trusty.
Building gcc 4.2 is not an option so I need to get it through a repository(it's part of a Travis CI build for [project mutator](https://bloodstalker.github.io/mutator/) so I can't really build it).
I looked around and apparently Hardy(deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe) used to have that so I figured I just need to add that to the apt list but I get this:

```
Package gcc-4.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

So I looked around some more and couldn't find another repo with that package.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Hardy and Trusty is quite big. Too big to do so-called apt-pinning.

It seems to me that the easiest and cleanest solution is to install Hardy in a Virtual Machine, and install gcc 4.2 there.

For example, after downloading the Hardy iso image and installing Qemu/KVM. Assuming you can run KVM (Otherwise just run plain Qemu or use VirtualBox) :

```
qemu-img -f qcow2 hardy-hdd.qcow2 15G
kvm -hda hardy-hdd.qcow2 -cdrom ubuntu-8.04-desktop-amd64.iso -boot d -m 1024
```

The first line created a virtual hard disk of 15 Gb called hardy-hdd.qcow2

The second line boots up the iso cdrom image, in order to install Ubuntu Hardy in the virtual hdd.